# In Rails how to receive data for marked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my index page I have:

```
<% @book.each_slice(2) do |book, b| %>
 <%= book.title %>
 <%= book.description %>
 <%= link_to 'Order', order_books_path(:id => book.id)%>
<% if b %>
 <%= b.title %>
 <%= b.description %>
 <%= link_to 'Order', order_books_path(:id => book.id)%>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

The link hits the route to the order page successfully and the url indicates the number associated with the book (example:/book/order.2).

Where I'm struggling is indicating on the order page book 2.

In my order page I have:

```
<% @book.each_slice(2) do |book, b| %>
 <%= book.title %>
 <%= book.description %>

 <% if b %>
 <%= b.title %>
 <%= b.description %>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

In essence how do I receive and mark with CSS from Rails?

For my controller at the moment I have:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
 def index
 @book = Book.all
 end

 def order
  @book = Book.all
 end

 def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
 end

 end
```

I can do this with jQuery (CSS), JS (collecting/parsing variable), and HTML(contains variable) but I've no idea how to apply with Rails.

EDIT: I updated my links on the index to pass the book id as the parameter. Then for the order page I'm guessing the collection needs to take place on the HTML to mark for select. So I've updated my order page to something close to this:

```
<% @book.each_slice(2) do |books| %>
 <div class="row">
  <% books.each do |book| %>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="book-container <% selected if book.id == params[:id] %>">
    <%= book.title %>
    <%= book.description %>
```

This doesn't work but am I headed in the right direction to mark for active with using <% selected if book.id == params[:id]%>?

Comment: Really love getting a down vote without a reasoning.

Comment: I think it is hard to tell what you mean by "In essence how do I receive and mark with CSS from Rails?".

Comment: I'm looking for the equivalent of the order page looking for a variable upon page load to then apply css. In my JS/jQuery method I have a function look for attributes, compare with a variable on the elements, and if matched apply CSS.

Comment: Hey @Jake, I am assuming `selected` is css class that you need to use to mark div, right ?

Comment: @AdittyaVerma you are correct

Comment: see my answer and let me know if this helps you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make change in existing line :

```
<%= selected if book.id == params[:id].to_i %>
```

**to_i** helps you to convert your string id into int. Hope this will help you.

Comment: So freaking close. This was the nudge I needed. <%= 'selected' if book.id == params[:id].to_i %>. The converting to string was missing and needed to put apostrophes around the class. Much appreciated!

Comment: Thank You. Happy that you found your solution.